# Hibernate @CollectionId has ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush

Tags: java, hibernate

I write some of this code in hibernate .In this code I want to insert a collection into database as new table , this code create table and mapped `foreign key` but couldn't insert data in table and throw exception .
this is my hibernate code :

```
@ElementCollection()
@JoinTable(name="user_address",
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userId")
)
@GenericGenerator(name = "hilo-gen", strategy ="hilo")
@CollectionId(columns = { @Column(name="address_id") }, generator ="hilo-gen", type =@Type(type="long"))
```

and this is some error :

```
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$5 mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Long]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Comment: Can you update your question with some more explanation of what you are trying to do, and what error you are getting?

Comment: What is merked by the annotation? Is it collection of Entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use different generator strategy.
`@GenericGenerator(name = "inc-gen", strategy ="increment")` should work fine.

Read more -> [5.1.2.2.1. Various additional generators.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5294)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,although I have this error `ERROR: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: If this is only a tutorial (JavaBrains :)), try to drop all the tables from database and run it again.

Comment: yes this is a tutorial (JavaBrains :) and some document of jboss. I drop all table but my problem doesn't solve and now say `ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long]`

Answer (score 0):

Add this file in hibernate.cfg.xml
    false

in database execute below script
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
    SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: To me it looks like MySQL solution. Without explanation that brings not much value...